# Modify date query by URL parameter using pre_get_posts and $_GET

Tags: custom-field, query, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to use URL parameters to modify the query for my "event" custom post type by using a function like the [following](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/):

```
function my_pre_get_posts($query)
    {

    // do not modify queries in the admin

    if (is_admin())
        {
        return $query;
        }

    // only modify queries for 'event' post type

    if (isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'event')
        {

        // allow the url to alter the query

        if (isset($_GET['city']))
            {
            $query->set('meta_key', 'city');
            $query->set('meta_value', $_GET['city']);
            }
        }

    // return

    return $query;
    }

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

This works well when modifying the query with a string such as `www.website.com/events?city=melbourne`, but in my case I'd like to change the date range being queried from events that start on or after the current date to *before* the current date (using the custom field `event_start_date`). So my existing query looks like this:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'     =>  'event',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
        'posts_per_page'        => 10,
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
        'orderby'       =>  'meta_value_num',
        'order'         =>  'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'event_start_date',
                'type'    => 'DATE',
                'value'   => current_time('Ymd'),
                'compare' => '>=',
            ),
        ),
    );
```

Thus, how might I go about modifying the `pre_get_posts` function above to change the query by URL to `'<='` the current date? Thanks for any assistance here.

Comment: are you asking how to `unset` and then `set` the `compare` of the `meta_query`?

Comment: @hwl yes, exactly- how would I modify the query to `set` the `compare` via URL to `<` than the event_start_date custom field from `>=`? Thanks.

Comment: well, I was hoping to grab it directly, but didn't see a method. There could be one, but I've posted an answer that hopefully at least points in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

I'm not where I can test this, but for something like: `www.website.com/events?date=past`, perhaps an approach like that outlined below could work.

(I can almost guarantee a type or two, so be sure to rewrite/edit/rework this into your function and ensure you don't inherit my errors).

```
   if (isset($_GET['date']))
        {
           //using past, present, future as example. not sure what you wanted to pass in url
           switch( $_GET['date'] ) {
               case ('past'):
                     $compare = '<';
                     break;
               case ('present'):
                     $compare = '=';
                     break;
               case ('future'):
                     $compare = '>=';
                     break;
           }//switch

           // $metas will be array of arrays, and we only want one of those,
          //  otherwise we risk altering the compare value of the city or 
         //  some other meta query array

          //get existing meta_query from $query
           $metas = $query->get('meta_query'); 
           foreach ( $metas as $meta ) {

            //limit edits to the one we want, when we want it
            if ( $meta['key'] == 'event_start_date' && $meta['compare'] != $compare ) {

                //might not need to unset, as setting it will overwrite
                unset( $meta['compare'] ); 

                $meta['compare'] = $compare;

            }//if
          }//foreach

          //now that foreach is over, re-set() the whole meta query
          $query->set( 'meta_query', $metas );

    }//if (isset)
```

---

### Unrelated

Also, be mindful that your

```
if (isset($_GET['city']))
    {
    $query->set('meta_key', 'city');
    $query->set('meta_value', $_GET['city']);
    }
}
```

might be overwriting an existing meta query (I'm unsure if adding it that way appends, prepends, or replaces anything being handled by `WP_Meta_Query`.)
In any event, using `$query->get('meta_query');` first can allow you to add another array of args to the meta_query:

```
$meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');
$my_new_meta_query = array(
                          array(
                               'key'     => 'city',
                               'value'   => $_GET['city'],
                               ),
                      );
$meta_query[] = $my_new_meta_query;
```

I only add that in case your intention was to build meta queries with url params such as `www.website.com/events?date=past&city=melbourne`. etc.

Comment: thanks very much for the answer @hwl- I've added your solution, but PHP is throwing an error of `Call to undefined function set()`- any ideas?

Comment: oh wait, brain lapse on my end. just do: `$meta['compare'] = $compare;`

Comment: hm, no more PHP error, but now all url parameter variants, e.g. `website.com/events?date=past` are returning all results?

Comment: lets make sure these are changing correctly. BEFORE the foreach, add a `print_r( $metas)` and then AFTER `$query->set( 'meta_query', $metas );` add a `$metas = $query->get('meta_query'); print_r($metas);` and see if you can confirm that.

Comment: I'm wondering if perhaps an additional `$query->set` needs to be applied? If I add `$query->set('meta_value', $_GET['date']);` under `$query->set( 'meta_query', $metas );` it returns no results, but clearly the query is at least being modified...

Comment: Here's what I'm getting with your test: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => event_start_date [type] => DATE [value] => 20170804 [compare] => >= ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => event_start_date [type] => DATE [value] => 20170804 [compare] => >= ) )`

Comment: ok, so that's the same as default and future. if your url param was anything else, then we aren't getting that changed. 1) after `switch { }`, `printf( $compare);` and see that a url param of `past` gets a `<`. if so, we will look at the foreach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63339/discussion-between-hwl-and-nickpish).